# Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given

Tags: php, sql-server, database, iis

**Setup**

MS IIS server

MSSQL DB Server

PHP

**Error**

```
Warning: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\creating_new_table.php on line 36
Table creation failed with error:\n
Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_get_last_message() in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\creating_new_table.php on line 39
```

**Code**

```
$serverName ="NAME\SQLEXPRESS";
$usr="sa";
$pwd="pasw";
$db="DBNAME";

$connectionInfo = array("UID" => $usr, "PWD" => $pwd, "Database" => $db);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn )
{
    echo "Connected";
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$sql = "CREATE TABLE fyi_links ("
    . " id INT NOT NULL VARCHAR (6)" 
    . ", url VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL"
    . ", notes VARCHAR(1024)"
    . ", counts INT"
    . ", time DATETIME"
    . ")";
$res = sqlsrv_query($sql,$conn);
if (!$res) {
    print('Table creation failed with error:\n');
    print("   ".sqlsrv_get_last_message()."\n");
}
else {
    print("Table fyi_links created.\n");
}  

mssql_close( $conn);
```

Connection is fine but something happens with my create table script.

Comment: `" id INT NOT NULL VARCHAR (6)" ` WTF?!?

Comment: Im just beginer for mssql. Sorry for that

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: The only way a column can have two different datatypes such as varchar and int at the same time is if you're using the Schrödinger database engine, and even then the datatype is only both until you actually observer it, whereupon it resolves into one or the other datatype

Comment: Another error:Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_get_last_message() in

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of [sqlsrv_errors()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) rather than `sqlsrv_get_last_message()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$res = sqlsrv_query($sql,$conn);` should be `$res = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);`

See the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-query.php

Comment: @klapsius Good to hear, please mark my answer as correct, cheers

Comment: Another error:Fatal error: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_get_last_message() in

Comment: Perhaps you're thinking of [sqlsrv_errors()](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-errors.php) rather than `sqlsrv_get_last_message()`